# Python script for Modbus RTU slave

Tags: modbus, plc, pymodbus, slave

I want to make a script so that my controller acts as a **Modbus RTU** slave and reacts to request sent by another device.

The controller stores 10 booleans as 10 discrete inputs from address 1 to 10. They can only be read (fonction code 2).

As I understood, pymodbus can be used for this. My question is: is it how I'm supposed to set up a Modbus RTU slave? But because I get errors, do you know what I am doing wrong?

Here is the script that I'm trying to execute:

```py
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from serial import Serial
import time
import sys
import random

# Create a serial port
serial = Serial(port='COM1',
                baudrate=9600,
                bytesize=8,
                parity='N',
                stopbits=1,
                timeout=0.5)

# Create a Modbus server context
store = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di=ModbusSequentialDataBlock.create(),
    co=ModbusSequentialDataBlock.create(),
    hr=ModbusSequentialDataBlock.create(),
    ir=ModbusSequentialDataBlock.create(),
    zero_mode=True
)

# Create a loop to change the discrete input from adress 1 to 10 every 2 seconds
while True:
    try:
        # Change the discrete input randomly
        for i in range(1, 11):
            store.setValues(1, i, [random.randint(0, 1)])
        time.sleep(2)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop()
        sys.exit()
```

My controller has a Windows OS and can execute python. It has a **RS-232** port (DB9).

My testing set-up is a computer with **QModMaster** on it to try and read my discrete inputs.

Is it how a **Modbus RTU** slave should be set up?

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... The error message I get from **QModMaster** is just a time out error.

Comment: You need to call [`StartSerialServer`](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/server.html#pymodbus.server.StartSerialServer) (or one of the other options) to actually run the server (currently you are just creating `serial` and `store` but not using them in a server). See [this example](https://pymodbus-n.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/source/example/asynchronous_server.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do I have to run a server eventhough I want to make my controler act as a slave?

Comment: Modbus terminology can be a bit confusing; effectively to translate to client/server terminology: Master=Client and Slave = Server (the slave awaits a request with it's address and then responds; this is effectively what a server does).

Comment: Thanks! However, the function StartSerialServer isn't available in the last version of PyModbus (version 3.0.0) and I couldn't find the equivalent. Do you have an idea of the updated version of the function?

Comment: Latest release is v3.6.6, this includes [`StartSerialServer`](https://github.com/pymodbus-dev/pymodbus/blob/v3.6.6/pymodbus/server/async_io.py#L701) or see [the example](https://github.com/pymodbus-dev/pymodbus/blob/v3.6.6/examples/server_sync.py#L90).